# LDAP search with some kind of TRUE statement, postfix related

Tags: ldap, postfix-mta

Is it possible to make a filter containing some kind of true statement, i.e.
(&(objectClass=SomeObject)('somestr'='somestr'))

In more details. I want postfix ldap filter that return all mails to implement all@domain mail list without manually place all mails in some list. So it must return values only if given string contain this all@. The current string in my .cf file is:

query_filter = (&(&(%s=all@domain.ltd)(objectClass=PostfixailAccount))(PostfixaccountActive=TRUE))

and obviously it does not work.

Any tips?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're lookin for. When you say "all mails to implement all@domain mail list", do you mean you want return only users who are a member of a specific distribution list?

Comment: Also, what is your LDAP server (Active Directory, OpenLDAP, etc.)?